# Class not found in PhoneGap with cordova-plugin-googleplus

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am having a problem with this plugin. I am building a non-Ionic app with PhoneGap. When first implemented this I was getting an error: 10 but now don't get any alerts but in logcat, it says `Class not found when unmarshalling`. And when i want to log my webClientId i get Error in `Success callbackId: GooglePlus1684379192 : ReferenceError: webClientId is not defined`.

**Version**

`phonegap version` 7.1.1

```
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
```

**Code**

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
      // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
      'webClientId': '52tralalalalalalalalal1l7.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
      'offline': true, // optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
    },
    function (obj) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); // do something useful instead of alerting
    },
    function (msg) {
      alert('error: ' + msg);
    }
);
window.plugins.googleplus.getSigningCertificateFingerprint(
  function (fingerprint) {
            console.log('##FINGERPRINT##');
            console.log(fingerprint);  //prints B0:B9:something:7E:3E
            console.log('##webClientId##');
            console.log(webClientId); //prints 52tralalalalalalalalal1l7.apps.googleusercontent.com
 });
```

**Logcat**
Part where i get `Class not found`

```
E/Parcel  (  726): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration

E/Parcel  (  726): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration

E/Parcel  (  726):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

Part where i get `webClientId is not defined`

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient( 4185): file:///android_asset/www/js/my-app.js: Line 2972 : ##webClientId##

I/chromium( 4185): [INFO:CONSOLE(2972)] "##webClientId##", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/my-app.js (2972)

D/SystemWebChromeClient( 4185): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 312 : Error in Success callbackId: GooglePlus1684379192 : ReferenceError: webClientId is not defined

I/chromium( 4185): [INFO:CONSOLE(312)] "Error in Success callbackId: GooglePlus1684379192 : ReferenceError: webClientId is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (312)
```

**OAuth** 
[image]